# Use asp.net expression to define server tag in text value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I have a function in codebehind and want to use it on aspx.

codebehind :

```
    public string GetTranslate(string Text)
    {
       return Glob.GetTranslate(Text);
    }
```

aspx :

```
<asp:LinkButton Text='<%= GetTranslate("Admin_HeaderInfo")%>' id="blabla" runat="server" />
```

result :

```
LinkButton Text On Page => "<%= GetTranslate("Admin_HeaderInfo")%>"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `<%` and `%>` inside a server a tag with `runat="server"`. You can set that property from code.

Comment: Yes if the link must be runat=server, otherwise don't use runat=server and that syntax will work.

Comment: yes you can - with an expression builder http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx

Comment: @RichardFriend an expression builder is pretty different! He has to call a method (static in the class or from the Page object) with parameters (in this case a constant but it's not a rule). They have **really** different purposes. If you have to write code...well first you should ask yourself why you can't do it with...code.

Comment: I disagree - how is it any less code than a normal data binding expression is code :  you write code for the expression builder and markup to use it. Sounds like code to me..

Comment: @RichardFriend well, it may be a point of view but I see expression builder as something _static_. If you need an explicit method call or some logic (even if you may use C.E.B.) then I think it's more clear to put that in codebehind (at least it'll make you page more readable). Moreover I should say I think in this case (for translation) he shouldn't force to use code but he may **refactor** to use as an expression builder in the way they're intended: `Text='<%$ Translate : Admin_HeaderInfo %>'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DataBinding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860), i.e. `<%#`, however then you will need to explicitly call `DataBind()` from your code behind, i.e.

.aspx

```
<asp:LinkButton  Text='<%#GetTranslate("Admin_HeaderInfo")%>' id="blabla" runat="server" />
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blabla.DataBind();
    }
```

As Adriano mentioned, the other way is to set it from code behind, e.g.:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blabla.Text = GetTranslate("Admin_HeaderInfo");
    }
```

Note that you will need to take PostBack and page lifecycle aspects into account when using determining where to place the code behind.

Answer (score 2):

We have used `ExpressionBuilders` in the past for this type of thing, they work pretty well and are available even if you are not databinding.

We use the [Code Expression Builder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx) in some of our older WebForms projects.

See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125044/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx) for other details about Expression Builders

This will allow you a syntax like

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%$ Lookup : SomeLookupValue %>'></asp:Label>
```

[More explained on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934160/asp-net-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the method static and try this:

```
<%# GetTranslate("Admin_HeaderInfo")%>
```

Comment: Sorry I thought you were binding.