# ASP.NET: $ meaning in <%$ %> in ConnectionString for SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net

What does the dollar sign `$` mean in `<%$ %>` in the **ConnectionString** property for **SqlDataSource** control. An example is below.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LocalDB%>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM TableName"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the expression builder syntax for ASP.NET, have a look at this question for more information [asp.net <%$ ... %> syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934160/asp-net-syntax)